# Is it possible to start playing audio and mute others when app is backgrounded?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avaudiosession

I made an app that starts playing audio when app is backgrounded. 
I start `AVAudioSession` by:

```
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .duckOthers)
} catch {

}
```

It's working fine, but is it possible to mute any other audio from other apps when my app starts playing audio?

Without duckOthers option app crashes, because the code above is executed in background. And with duckOthers, it won't mute other audio, just reduces volume.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can duck other audio, and you can *interrupt* (pause, not mute) spoken audio (`interruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers`), but muting all other audio is not allowed. This is pretty clearly by design intent, since muting all audio typically is a pretty bad user experience, so even if you found a trick to work around it, you should expect trouble during AppStore review. Apple even calls out their intent in the `interruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers` docs:

> Ducking other audio, rather than interrupting it, is appropriate when the other audio is not spoken audio.